language $L,$ if $L\in \textbf{ZPP}$, then there exists a Turing machine that flips coins
I Followed from Barak and Arora book:

For a language $L$, we define $x\in L \Leftrightarrow L(x) =1$.
$\textbf{RP}$- is the collection of all languages ​​$L$ for which there exists a polynomial coin-imposing Turing machine $\textbf{M}$ such that for every $x\in \{0, 1\}^*$ there exists:

$x\in L \implies \text{Pr[$M(x)=L(x)$]}\geq 2/3$
$x\not\in L \implies \text{Pr[$M(x)=L(x)$]}= 1$

$\textbf{coRP}$- It collects all languages ​​L such that $\bar{L}\in \textbf{RP}$
We will define $\textbf{ZPP}$ to be the collection of all languages ​​$L$ for which there exists a Turing machine tossing coins $N$ and there exists a polynomial $q(.)$ , so that for every $x\in \{0, 1\}^*$ there exists:

$\text{Pr[$N(x)=L(x)$]}=1)$ ($N$ Always answers correctly) .

Calculated at least $0.5$ in probability, i.e. ($\text{Pr[N() halts within (||) steps}] > 1/2$ stops after at most $q(n)$ steps on an input of length $n$ - as the probability is above coins
the randomness of the machine).


My question is how to Show that for a language $L,$ if $L\in \textbf{ZPP}$, then there exists a Turing machine that flips coins $N'$ and there exists a polynomial $q'(.)$ such that for every $x\in \{0, 1\}^*$ there exists:

$\text{Pr[$N'(x)=L(x)$]}=1)$ ($N$ Always answers correctly).
$\text{Pr[N() halts within (||) steps}] > 1- 2^{-|x|}?$


Where does this appear in Arora and Barak? Also what does the definition of RP and coRP have to do with the question?

@spaceisdarkgreen this question, I asked in my midterm test, my professor said it's influenced from Barak and Arora book. Would you give me some insights about this question?
